# Is it possible to save a location in the savedInstanceState? Perhaps in a bundle?

Tags: android, location

Is it possible to save a location in the savedInstanceState? Perhaps in a bundle?  If I need to save it in a bundle how do I access it again (in onCreate())?

Answer (score 2):

Since `Location` implements `Parcelable`, you can save it within `onSaveInstanceState()` by using `Bundle.putParcelable()`. Then, you can retrieve it in `onRestoreInstanceState()` by using `Bundle.getParcelable()`.

Answer (score 1):

In your Activity implement `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` which should return the Object you want to save. Then you can retrieve it via `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()`.

Described here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html